# Calling the ListView items widgets from the activity without calling onItemClickListener.

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I am trying to set the items within the listview to be visible or not visible without onItemClickListener from the activity. How could call the widget (checkbox) from the listview within the activity? *not just a single list item, I want to set the visibility in all of the items.

**MainActivity**

```
LogsArrayAdapterBreakfast logsAdapter1 = new LogsArrayAdapterBreakfast(
        this, 4, LogBreakfast.logsByDate(currentDate));
ListView listBreakfast = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewBreakfast);
listBreakfast.setAdapter(logsAdapter1);
View vv = (View) listBreakfast.getParent();
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) vv.findViewById(R.id.cbDelete);
cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**Adapter**

```
public class LogsArrayAdapterBreakfast extends ArrayAdapter<LogBreakfast> {
    private static LogsArrayAdapterBreakfast instance;
    Context mContext;
    public static List<LogBreakfast> mLogs;
    public LogsArrayAdapterBreakfast(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<LogBreakfast> logs) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        mLogs = logs;
    }
    public void setLogs(List<LogBreakfast> logs) {
        mLogs = logs;
    }
    public List<LogBreakfast> getLogs() {
        return mLogs;
    }
    public void add(LogBreakfast log) {
        mLogs.add(log);
    }
    public void remove(LogBreakfast log) {
        LogsArrayAdapterBreakfast.mLogs.remove(log);
    }
    public static LogsArrayAdapterBreakfast getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LogsArrayAdapterBreakfast(
                    mContext.getApplicationContext(), 4, mLogs);
        }
        return instance;
    }
    /**
     * returns the number of logs that will appear in the listview
     * 
     * @return [int] number of logs
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return mLogs.size();
    }
    /**
     * returns the log found at the index of the position parameter
     * 
     * @return [Log]
     */
    public LogBreakfast getItem(int position) {

        return mLogs.get(position);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LogRowBreakfast view = (LogRowBreakfast) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new LogRowBreakfast(mContext);
        }
        LogBreakfast log = getItem(position);
        view.setLog(log);
        return view;
    }
    public boolean isItemChecked(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Row**

```
public class LogRowBreakfast extends LinearLayout {
    Context mContext;
    LogBreakfast mLog;
    public LogRowBreakfast(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        setup();
    }
    public LogRowBreakfast(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        setup();
    }
    private void setup() {
        LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater1.inflate(R.layout.log_row_breakfast, this);
    }
    public void setLog(LogBreakfast log) {
        mLog = log;
        TextView tvName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log_meal_name1);
        tvName1.setText(mLog.getMealName() + "");

        TextView tvCalories1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log_calories1);
        tvCalories1.setText(mLog.getCalorieCount() + " Cals");
    }
}
```

I am getting a nullpointerexception.

```
11-25 17:22:17.452: W/dalvikvm(24573): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4178ada0)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573): Process: com.theworkoutcalculator, PID: 24573
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.theworkoutcalculator/com.theworkoutcalculator.Activities.CaloriesLogMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at com.theworkoutcalculator.Activities.CaloriesLogMainActivity.onCreate(CaloriesLogMainActivity.java:673
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
11-25 17:22:17.452: E/AndroidRuntime(24573):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: So you can see in the log that you have a NullPointerException on line 673. Which code is on that line?

Comment: @greenapps the null pointer is CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) vv.findViewById(R.id.cbDelete);

Comment: So what do you think is null?

Comment: @greenapps the checkbox is not in the layout of the activity it is in the custom layout for the listvivew.

Comment: Yes that is what i already thought. So you ment the layout file for the listview items. But you are not answering my question.

Comment: @greenapps what is your question? I believe I have already answered your question.  the null pointer is "CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) vv.findViewById(R.id.cbDelete)" I think it is null because "the checkbox is not in the layout of the activity it is in the custom layout for the listvivew"

Comment: That is a code line you presented. A statement. Not a pointer that is null. So i ask you again "which pointer do you think is null"? And another question : Are you sure it is on this line and not the next one?

Comment: I apologize it is the next line.

Comment: Ok. But same question: what is null on that line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65710/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-greenapps).

Comment: No. Please answer here.

Comment: @greenapps I am clearly not understand what you are asking for.  If you can elaborate on your question I might be able to answer it.  It is becoming an extended discussion so I am trying to prevent that. The null is probably " vv."

Comment: The answer is wrong. Moreover there is no vv in that last line. Please try again.

Comment: @greenapps, cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  Can you help or no?

Comment: That is again a code line. A statement. Ofcourse i can help you. But first i want you to realise that you have a NullPointerException. So what is the pointer in that line? What is null?

Comment: @greenapps I believe it is means undefined object. I did not go to school for this so if I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: I did nit ask what it ment but to indicate the pointer that was null. There is only one pointer variable in that line. The pointer variable is `cb`. So cb==null. And you cannot call a member function (here setVisible()) on a pointer that is null. Hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: Now why is cb null? Well you used findViewById on the parent layout of the listview. It was not found there so findViewById returned null. You assigned thst null to cb so cb is null now,

Comment: As the checkbox is defined in the layout for the listview items you should take that layout. So more a child layout then a parent layout. But even this approach will bring you nowhere. No it has to be done quite different.

Comment: @greenapps  Thanks for that. I was trying to say earlier that the null pointer was pointing to the CheckBox.  Would you have any solution on fixing this issue?

Comment: Still wrong. The null pointer is not pointing to the checkbox. You can only say: The checkbox pointer cb is null. To fix in a complete ly different way you to have to add a `boolean cbVisible:` to your `LogBreakfast` class. Give it a true/false at init. Then adapt `setLog()`. Add code to set the visibility of the Checkbox. This is not all ofcourse. But the right start.

Comment: @greenapps thanks.  I am going to be honest with you.  You come off as an a-hole but I appreciate it.  It is important that I know this.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Android Programming. I am not sure this will work.

You could maybe try adding the checkbox to a ArrayList of Checkboxes.

Then setting the visibility to what you need.

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> checkboxlist = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
 checkboxlist.add(cb);
```

This is not a complete solution but a simple approach to one. 
Add all the checkboxes to a list when you add a checkbox.
Then you can set the visibility of what checkboxes you need.